# SQL statement for current line out of log table

Tags: sql

I have a table with four columns: Type, SubT, Info and Timestamp.
Type and SubT are type and subtype of the entry, Info is a string which is different foe each row and Timestamp the day/time when the entry happened.

I search a SQL statement which gives me in one query the current (with respect to Timestamp) rows for each Type and SubT including all other columns.

So, with this data:

```
Type | SubT | Info              | Timestamp
-----+------+-------------------+--------------
   1 |    2 | Hello             | 20190223T1300
   1 |    3 | Fuuuu             | 20190223T1301
   1 |    3 | Baaar             | 20190223T1400
   3 |    2 | Something         | 20190222T1300
```

I would like to get that result:

```
Type | SubT | Info              | Timestamp
-----+------+-------------------+--------------
   1 |    2 | Hello             | 20190223T1300
   1 |    3 | Baaar             | 20190223T1400
   3 |    2 | Something         | 20190222T1300
```

In other words:
All columns for each existing combination of Type and SubT and if there are several rows for one Type/SubT, then the one with the youngest timestamp.

To generalize: there could be more then two "distinct" columns like Type and SubT and there could be more then one column like info which is taken from the row with the most current timestamp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Both solutions do work (join and correlated subquery).
With a table of 15271 entries and NO indexes, the correlated subquery needs more then 100 sec whereas the join delivers in 0.08 secs.
With indexes the correlated subquery needs 2 secs and the join 0.06 secs.

I still have to figure out, why the join delivers 11363 and the subquery 11312 rows!

Comment: Figured it out:
The join-solution must also check the timestamp. With that corrected, both solutions get the same results, but the join is in my environment faster (x100).

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below.

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
inner join (select type, subt, min(timestamp) group by type, sub) a
on (t1.type = t2.type and t1.subt = t2.subt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simple method is a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.type = t.type and t2.subt = t.subt
                    );
```

In many databases, this will be a highly performant solution, particularly with an index on `(type, subt, timestamp desc)`.

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subwuery

```
    select t1.* from table t1
      where t1.Timestamp=( select max(Timestamp) from table t2
                        where t1.SubT =t2.SubT and t1.type=t2.type
                      )
```

or `row_number()`which support most dbms

```
select * from 
(
  select *,row_number()over(partition by subT,type order by Timestamp desc) rn
   from table 
) t where t.rn=1
```